# How to update users list on display page when new user is added to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I am displaying users list in a div  and  I want to update a div with new users  without refreshing page . I want to call a sever file only when new user added to the database like `Gmail inbox/chat list`  update.

If I call a file through ajax by giving setInterval for 5 seconds, page is get  strucking after some  time.

What's better solution for this. Can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Do you need real time updating or what?

Comment: Yes I need real time updating

Comment: For a real time updating, I would suggest you to use nodejs. However, if you already have your system built in somewhere and you can't use nodejs, then the only solution, as far as I know, is using AJAX and, as you've already done that, update some sections of the page every X seconds, maybe **asyncronously**.

Comment: Show us your ajax code, sounds like you have created a memory leak somehow - the easiest thing to do would be to try and fix this